# Laravel route with multiple parameters not working

Tags: laravel

Im trying to define a GET route in laravel with two parameters, but I keep getting a (laravel) 404 page.

my route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/swapslot/{og}/{new}', 'ItemController@swapSlot')->name('swapslot');
```

whenever I redirect my users to `public/swapslot/*number*/*number*` I get a 404 error. I have other routes with *1* parameter, these *do* work.

Comment: `'swapslot/{og}/new/{new}'` try making your URL something like this

Comment: Elaborate on what the og and new represent, aswell does the function in the controller accept two parameters?

Comment: Provide your controller function and also how are you making the request. Also, this route is defined in the `web.php` o `api.php`. Paste as well the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @Miaan the controller function does accept two parameters. OG is the original inventory slot i'm moving an item from, NEW is the new inventory slot i'm moving an item to.

Comment: @HCK it's defined in web.php. I'm linking the user to ```public/swapslot/number/number``` using a javascript function. Cant post the output of that command atm since im @ work.

Comment: Can you try with single parameter

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is different than I would've expected. Turns out nothing was wrong with my route definition. I was using the eloquent model function `findOrFail` which sends a 404 HTTP response to the user if it doesn't find the ID it's looking for. Thats why I was getting a 404 page.

Comment: Just a heads up. This is why you need to give more info when asking a question. Like in this case, give the parameters you're sending, the route as well as the controller function.